# Is there an API for iOS's Assistive Touch Feature?

Tags: ios, accessibility, gestures

Does iOS SDK provide framework or API for us to use their Custom Gesture creation?

Answer (score 2):

There is no public API for either accessing the existing Assistive Touch feature (it has to be turned on by the user in the settings) or for creating a similar UI.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can find a list of accessibility features for which APIs exist [here](https://developer.apple.com/accessibility/ios/).  Assistive touch is not one of them.